# Why can I use a method that says "Added in API 16" when I'm supporting down to API 11 in Android?

Tags: android, api, deprecated

The method is ImageButton's setImageAlpha(), and it says in the documentation that it was "Added in API 16."

But it doesn't give me an error when I try to use it, unlike some other methods that get underlined red and tell me it's not supported by the API I'm supporting?

Comment: Are you testing it on a API 11 device/emulator?

Comment: what is your min and max sdk level and for which api target are you compiling the app?

Comment: min is 11, target is 17

Comment: Are you sure you are not overriding the lint check with `@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)` or `@SuppressLint("NewApi")` somewhere in that class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the largest reasons Android will not error out these methods is that some methods introduce a cleaner/faster way to accomplish a task, which is great to include for users with a higher API level. A simple API level `if check` can allow users with a higher API level to user the cleaner/faster approach while not crashing the app for a device with a lower API level.

Erroring out the method would prevent you from supporting newer methods for users with a higher API, while still supporting devices with a lower API.

Comment: So I can't just use it without issues?  I'd have to actually provide an alternate method for devices that don't support it?

Comment: Try it out ^.^ It "should" crash for any device with API 15 or below if the method was introduced in API level 16.